# How to make an Instant Shorten link for a url shortener

Tags: php, javascript, url

I have recently made a [url shortener](http://n1x.co.uk) and I want to make an "Instant Shorten" Bookmark link on my site, like [YOURLS](http://yourls.org/#About) can, so you bookmark the link, then go to any webpage, then you click on the bookmark and it automatically shortens the address, adds it to the database and tells you the shortened url in a pop-up.

I'm not sure how to do this, please help me!

**Edit:** This is the code that YOURLS currently uses to shorten using the bookmark link:

`javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20d=document,s=d.createElement('script');window.yourls_callback=function(r)%7Bif(r.short_url)%7Bprompt(r.message,r.short_url);%7Delse%7Balert('An%20error%20occured:%20'+r.message);%7D%7D;s.src='http://nix-pix.co.uk/public/admin/index.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(d.location.href)+'&jsonp=yourls';void(d.body.appendChild(s));%7D)();`

Comment: I don't work with PHP but couldn't you just have it shorten the HTTP referrer via `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Comment: You mean you do not know what technology to use?. In this case I think the best should be using AJAX to communicate with your application and seek.

Comment: So you have the javascript and you have already transplanted a URL for your site into it - what else do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a bookmarklet something like this is used:

```
javascript:u=encodeURIComponent(location.href);s='http://urlshortener.com/shorten.php?url='+u;window.open(s,'shortened','location=no,width=400,height=300');
```

That takes the URL of the current page and opens a new window pointing to urlshortener.com/shorten.php?url=[the url to be shortened]. The code used by YOURLS is more complicated, but probably does approximately the same thing. You just need to change the URL that the new window opens to in the code above.